# How do I minus data from query?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

this is my sample query

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dataweb WHERE web LIKE 'google%'ORDER BY ASC LIMIT 8");
```

the above query is to find similar domains. but I want to remove all aka google results...which means the result return like google.com,google.br,google.de etc.

I want only restdomains which start from google..

Comment: Please give an example of a domain that should be returned. Your sentence "I want only restdomains which start from google" is very hard to understand.

Answer (score 7):

To do this, make it NOT LIKE instead

Comment: @limo - It may not work because of ORDER BY ASC... ORDER BY needs a column name (or position) to order on, it will complain about a column name that it thinks as called ASC, because ASC is a reserved word

Comment: Good spotting Mark, missed that.  Yes it should be ORDER BY (some column) ASC.  Limo, a good way to debug it (or anything for that matter) is to strip it back to bare bones and keep adding conditions, see where it breaks.

Answer (score 3):

You want domains that begin with `google` but not `google.`? You can use `REGEXP` for this.

```
SELECT web
FROM   (SELECT 'google.com' AS web UNION ALL
        SELECT 'google.co.uk' UNION ALL
        SELECT 'google.br' UNION ALL
        SELECT 'google.de' UNION ALL
        SELECT 'googleplex.com' UNION ALL
        SELECT 'google-watch.org' UNION ALL
        SELECT 'ooglegoogle.com') dataweb
WHERE  web REGEXP '^google[^.].'
ORDER  BY web ASC
LIMIT  8
```

Returns

```
web
----------------
google-watch.org
googleplex.com
```